# Merge two tables in SQL Server 2008 while renumbering primary key column value

Tags: sql-server-2008, merge

I have two tables `tab1` and `tab2` (with identical schema) that reside in different databases.
These tables have a primary key column `aud_ID` whose values can be similar.

Please note the primary key column `aud_ID` is not a identity column.

I have task to merge data of two tables in a third table `tab3` (with identical schema).
The challenge here is to renumber the primary key column value of `tab3`.

1. Either the primary key column of `tab1` is copied first into `tab3` and then `tab2` data will be inserted into `tab3` starting the max value of `tab1.aud_id`.

   OR
2. The primary key column `aud_id` is renumbered from 1.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Regards,
Prashant..

Comment: Do you care if any of the `aud_ID` values are maintained? If not, then can you just renumber all rows? If so then the solution is quite simple...

Comment: Of course, if the primary keys are referenced by any foreign keys set in other tables, the problem gets slightly more complex...

Comment: @PhilipKelley I have to assume since the OP is throwing away the existing values in tab2 that there isn't any relationship to maintain.

Comment: @PhilipKelley the primary keys are not referenced to any other tables..

Answer (score 2):

If the `aud_id` values are numeric (and you don't need to avoid gaps), you could do:

```
insert into tab3 (/* Columns */)
select (aud_id *2)-1,/* Other Columns */ from tab1
union all
select (aud_id *2),/* Other Columns */ from tab2
```

That way, you guarantee to generate unique values, without having to inspect either table. And by keeping it formulaic, you can use it to copy references from other tables, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't need to keep any of the existing `aud_ID` values:

```
INSERT dbo.tab3(aud_ID, other cols)
SELECT aud_ID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY aud_ID), other cols
FROM
(
  SELECT aud_ID, other cols FROM dbo.tab1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT aud_ID, other cols FROM dbo.tab2
) AS x;
```

Comment: Thanks @Aron...it is making sense...any suggestions if I have to keep the aud_id value of tab1 and then renumber for tab2 starting from the maximum value of tab1?

Comment: did you forget `INTO` just after `INSERT` ??

Comment: @Bellash no, I didn't forget it. INTO is optional, and leaving it does not cause confusion or ambiguity. How else would you insert? OUT_OF? BESIDE? NEARBY?